# c++ How to extract numbers from a string that has backslash?

Tags: c++, regex, string, extract, precision

I am trying to extract numbers from a string.
I would like to save each number to a separate double variable.
I currently tried using a simple stringstream like this.

```
std::string line = "100.2456426246\200.2624362436\300.136213477347";
std::stringstream stream(line);
stream.precision(20);
double a,b,c;
stream >> a >> b >> c;
```

Not only is the precision wrong(only prints out 6 digits), it only extracts the first number a(100.245), and b and c is null. I suspect it is due to backslash, but I'm not exactly sure.

What is the best way to read the string which contains backslash between each number and store the whole number with correct precision?

Comment: How could it possibly know that you want to split your string on slashes?

Comment: For "only 6 digits": [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: The string `"100.2456426246\200.2624362436\300.136213477347"` doesn't contain any backslashes! But it does contain some unusual non-ASCII characters.

Comment: First you need to escape the backslashes in the string literal- `"100.2222\\2000.2000\\300.333"`

Comment: @Drop if I'm doing my math right, `double` should have a good 13 digits of precision after the decimal in the vicinity of 100.

Comment: @hobbs I just realized it's double, not float. Anyway this classic article will never hurt. ;)

Comment: You can use `ignore` to ignore the delimiter after reading the number. You can also use `peek` to assert that the delimiter is the backslash you expect. Example: http://ideone.com/qqj0Vs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `getline` with a delimiter to split a string into a vector of elements and `atof` to extract floats along these lines

```
vector<string> elems;
stringstream stream(line);
string item;
while (getline(stream, item, "\\")) {
  elems.push_back(item);
}
vector<float> val(elems.size());
...
val[i]=atof(elems[i].c_str())
```

Precision here is more of a matter of presentation, which you can customize with the help of `setprecision`. For example,

```
#include <iomanip>
... 
cerr << setprecision(6) << val[i] << endl;
```

will output the truncation to six significant digits.

Another matter is making sure that all digits up to the last one are stored. To make sure that all digits are stored, simply the size of your defined float must be sufficiently large to contain your data, and `atof` may need to be replaced by an appropriate parser if float should be replaced by `double` or something else.

Comment: Thank you very much it helped me alot!